# git: синхронизировать ветки после коммита

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-merge

Работа ведется в ветке **develop**, перед релизом все мерджится в **master** и пушится на сервер.
Ситуация:
Есть файл, над которым в **develop** ведется работа:

```
old code
new develop code
```

то есть, имеется старый код и тот, который пишется.

Поступила задача сделать какой-то хотфикс на сервере в этом же файле. Мы переключаемся на **master** где файл имеет вид:

```
old code
```

пишем хотфикс прям в **master**-е и пушим. Файл имеет вид

```
old code

hotfix code
```

Далее доделываем работу в **develop** , переключаемся на **master** мерждим и пушим.
В итоге в master код имеет вид

```
old code
new develop code
hotfix code
```

**Теперь вопрос:**

Цикл начинается сначала - берем следующую задачу, начинаем ее делать в **develop**, но ...

там все еще файлы в состоянии

```
old code
new develop code
```

то есть в ветке есть не все изменения.

#### Собсвенно, как правильно тут поступать?

Отпочковать от **мастера** новую ветку **develop2**? Но тогда со временем веток будет слишком много.

Или можно как-то ветку **develop** привести к состоянию **master**?

Comment: а мердж из **master** в **develop** чем не устраивает? Переключаетесь на **develop**  и мержите c **master**. После этого в ветке **develop** есть ваши изменения из **master**.

Comment: Тогда у меня  в девелопе будут все изменения, но в мастер изменения девелопа не попадут . Или надо 2 раза мерджить ? Сначала слить все в мастер, а потом переключаться на девелом и сливать еще раз ?

Comment: нужно переключиться в master, посмотреть hash коммита, потом перейти в develop и утянуть его `git cherry-pick <sha hash>`.

Comment: @KoVadim а какая разница  в этом случае будет, находясь в develop-е , делать мердж из master-а или cherry-pick ?

Comment: @volkoff, если все изменения из master в develop для вас не страшны, то сначала сливаете изменения из мастера в девелоп, потом наоборот, из девелопа в мастер. Будут обе ветки синхронизированы. Если же вы хотите, чтобы в девелоп оказался только этот один комит из мастера(не всю ветку сливаь), то тогда вам в комментарии KoVadim уже написал, как это сделать.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov Нет, наверное ваш способ правильнее - задача в том, чтоб когда работаешь в develop  - работать с актуальной версией. Спасибо

Comment: Если сливать туда-обратно не совсем правильно. Если это прибежал хотфикс в мастер, то его в девелом нужно утащить, а вот на этот момент девелоп заливать в мастер не нужно. Мастер должен содержать актуальный код прода. Поэтому нужно делать cherry-pick.

Comment: @KoVadim http://f5.s.qip.ru/u6bKe1zk.png   изобразил как мог)). Вот шаг получения хотфикса - разве мерждем не проще  будет ?

Comment: можно мерждем, можно ребейзом, хоть руками править все. Главное результат. Мне просто нравиться cherry-pick для этой ситуации. Но мой комментарий выше был о том, что девелом в мастер вливается только при релизе.

Comment: @KoVadim, поддерживаю cherry-pick! А еще можно не переключаться в мастер, а сделать 'git log --all ( --graph --oneline --decorate -5 добавить по вкусу)')

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, коллеги !! буду cherry-pick осваивать

Comment: **Если сливать туда-обратно не совсем правильно** Pазумеется, если у вас еще не релизное состояние, то из ветки **develop** вливать в **master** нельзя ни в коем случаи, делаем мерж только в одном направлении - из **master** в **develop**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> можно как-то ветку develop привести к состоянию master?

да, конечно, с помощью всё той же команды *merge*.

для контроля сначала можете посмотреть, какие коммиты есть в ветке *master*, которых нет в ветке *develop*:

```
$ git log develop..master
```

1. переключаетесь на ветку разработки:

   ```
   $ git checkout develop
   ```
2. делаете слияния тех самых недостающих коммитов из ветки *master*:

   ```
   $ git merge master
   ```

---

есть неплохая статья по одному из возможных вариантов организации работы с ветками:

- оригинал: [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)
- один из многочисленных переводов: [Удачная модель ветвления для Git](http://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)

Comment: благодарю! 
Примерно это и искал - инструкцию, **как работают с гитом пряморукие коллеги** )